# How Not to space the widgets within QHBoxLayout

Tags: python, pyqt

While using:

```
layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
layout.addWidget(QtGui.QPushButton())
layout.addWidget(QtGui.QPushButton())
layout.addWidget(QtGui.QPushButton())
```

the buttons get automatically spaced out within the width of the QHBoxLayout.
Instead I would like the buttons to be placed edge by edge next to each other.
I have tried to use :

```
    layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
    layout.importLayout.setSpacing(0)
```

but it has no effect on buttons spacing. What attribute of the `QHBoxLayout` needs to be set to override the auto spacing?

Comment: In QCreator (Qt & C++) I add `Horizontal Spacer` after buttons to move them to left.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your approach was already the right one. No contents margins on the layout as well as no spacing on the layout will put the buttons extremely close with a spacing of about 2 pixels. Negative margins set by a stylesheet can get the buttons further together but I don't recommend it because it doesn't look nice.

```
from PySide import QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
window = QtGui.QWidget()
window.setStyleSheet('QPushButton{margin-left:-1px;}') # remove this line if you want to have a tiny bit of spacing left

layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(window)
layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
layout.setSpacing(0)
layout.addWidget(QtGui.QPushButton('Button'))
layout.addWidget(QtGui.QPushButton('Button'))
layout.addWidget(QtGui.QPushButton('Button'))
layout.addWidget(QtGui.QPushButton('Button'))
layout.addWidget(QtGui.QPushButton('Button'))
layout.addWidget(QtGui.QPushButton('Button'))

window.show()

app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you wish to have negligible spacing between the pushButtons something like this.

[image]

Try using `layout.setSpacing(0)`

```
self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.widget)
self.horizontalLayout.setSpacing(0)
self.horizontalLayout.setMargin(0)
self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout"))
self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.widget)
self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
self.pushButton_2 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.widget)
self.pushButton_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_2"))
self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
self.pushButton_3 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.widget)
self.pushButton_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_3"))
self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
```